# Set default boot entry to Windows instead of Fedora

Tags: fedora, grub2, dual-boot, grub

I have the following options on my machine in Grub when I boot it up:

```
Fedora (5.10.21-200.fc33.x86_64) 33 (Workstation Edition)
Fedora (5.10.19-200.fc33.x86_64) 33 (Workstation Edition)
Fefora (5.8.15-301.fc33.x86_64) 33 (Workstation Edition)
Fedora (0-rescue-af432317147a47c59c193b055d8a658f) 33 (Workstation Edition)
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)
System setup
```

I want to change my default boot option to Windows. I read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/how-to-change-grub-2-default-permanently/60230) question on changing the boot priority, but when I ran the following command, nothing came up:

```bsh
grep "submenu\|^\smenuentry" /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

When I looked in the `/boot/loader/entries/` directory for `*.conf` files, the only things visible were these:

```
# ll /boot/loader/entries
total 16
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 410 Mar  6 16:35 af432317147a47c59c193b055d8a658f-0-rescue.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 337 Mar  6 17:39 af432317147a47c59c193b055d8a658f-5.10.19-200.fc33.x86_64.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 337 Mar 12 09:27 af432317147a47c59c193b055d8a658f-5.10.21-200.fc33.x86_64.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 334 Mar  6 16:35 af432317147a47c59c193b055d8a658f-5.8.15-301.fc33.x86_64.conf
```

So how do I set Windows as the default boot option?

Comment: Normally, you would do this by setting the GRUB_DEFAULT option in `/etc/default/grub`, then recreating `grub.cfg`. I guess the  [instructions for F18](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/sn-medialess-editing-grub-conf.html) are still correct.

Answer (score 7):

In Fedora 39 you do this:

1. make sure `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` is set in `/etc/default/grub`
2. `awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print $2}' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` which should output something like `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda4)`
3. `sudo grub2-set-default "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda4)"` change `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda4)` to the output of the second step
4. apply the setting with `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cf`

Pretty similar to what you do in older versions but grub.cfg has a new path and the last step is now vital.

---

The following is relevant as for Fedora 32/33/34. Like it often happens in Linux this manual might become outdated in the future.

1. First make sure `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` is set in `/etc/default/grub` - edit the file if necessary using `sudo` with `nano`, `vi`, `joe`.
2. Run

```bash
awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print $2}' /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda4)
System setup
```

to see your non-Fedora/non-Linux-kernel entries. The BIOS path for this file is `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

3. Run:

```bash
sudo grub2-set-default "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda4)"
```

`grub2-set-default` also takes a number as an argument. You're done.

---

You can also use `sudo efibootmgr --bootorder` to change your default EFI boot option though it's will not always work since lots of modern PCs have a zero boot delay, thus don't allow to press any keys to choose a non-default EFI boot option, i.e. you could lose access to your Fedora.

---

Fedora's documentation on grub2 can be found [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/).

Comment: Using `grub2-set-default` did not work: running `sudo grub2-set-default 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)'` yielded the following output: `/usr/bin/grub2-editenv: error: invalid environment block.` repeated three times. I rebooted and Fedora is still the default.

Comment: I did some googling, the recommendation for that error was to delete the `/boot/grub2/grubenv/` and `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv` files. I did that and the `grub2-set-default` command seemed like it worked (there was no output). However, upon rebooting, Fedora is *still* set to the default boot option, so `grub2-set-default` is not working.

Comment: @wheeler Can you show your `sudo head -n -1 /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv` ?

Comment: Also `sudo cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: The `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv` file does not exist. Here is the paste of the `/etc/default/grub` file: https://pastebin.com/b3W4LCeF

Comment: I don't know `ls -la /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv
-rw-------. 1 root root 1024 Sep  2 13:18 /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv` Here it exists and gets updated each time I boot.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you for sharing!
I'm curious how the AWK command extracts the name for the Windows boot entry. How can we modify it to read out the Fedora 39 entry in case we want to switch back?