# To make GRUB default to boot Windows 10 instead of Linux

Tags: grub, multiboot

How do I make GRUB default to boot (load bootloader of) Windows 10 if it's left untouched to get input on boot menu?

Comment: The easiest way is by setting `GRUB_DEFAULT` in /etc/default/grub. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/639010/set-default-boot-entry-to-windows-instead-of-fedora/639039#639039